# Borel Measures on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures, riesz-representation-theorem

My question is the following: do there exist Borel measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ such that, given a differentiable function $f$, we have
$$
f'(0) = \int_\mathbb{R} f d\mu - \int_\mathbb{R} f d\nu?
$$

I've been thinking about the one-to-one correspondence between Borel measures and (left) continuous increasing functions $F$ given by
$$
\mu((a,b]) := F(b) - F(a).
$$
I figure if I can choose an appropriate $F$, then the result would follow. I was also thinking that maybe the Riesz representation theorem is another approach, since differentiation is a linear map. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry, I see why $\mu$ has to have finite support but why does that give us non-existence of such measures?

Comment: You can easily find a smoth function $f$ such that $f=0$ on a given finite set and $f'(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible. The idea is that a function which is compactly supported and uniformly close to 0 must have small integral, but its derivative at 0 can still be big.

Let $\phi$ be some nonnegative smooth cutoff function which has support inside $[-1,1]$ and equals 1 on some neighborhood of 0.  If your equation is to hold for $\phi$, then in particular $\int \phi\,d\mu$ and $\int \phi\,d\nu$ must both be finite.  Now consider the function $f_n(t) = \frac{1}{n} \phi(t) \sin(n^2 t)$.  Note that $|f_n| \le \phi$ and $f_n \to 0$ pointwise (even uniformly), so  $\int f_n\,d\mu \to 0$ and $\int f_n\,d\mu \to 0$ by dominated convergence.   Thus the right side of the proposed equation goes to $0$.  But $f_n'(0) = n \to \infty$.